# buliding a website like dropthings

Tags: asp.net, ajax, dynamic, dashboard

I was assigned to develop a dropthings-like project http://dropthings.omaralzabir.com/ so do you have any clue from where should i start ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: That depends. What's your experience level, or is this your first programming project ever?

Comment: No Actually this is the first time i was asked to develop such a projct but i've been developing websites and web apps for about 3 years now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erm, you could try [downloading the project from Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/dropthings/) where it is hosted. And then you could buy the author's book [Building a Web 2.0 Portal with ASP.NET 3.5](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596510503/) where he explains how it was created.

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of information on the project's [website](http://code.google.com/p/dropthings/).

Comment: I know i did a lot of searching but it's very difficult to find a begining